# How to get the distance to the closest previous finite number in a row using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, missing-data

I'm stuck at something that I think could easily be solved in a couple of lines using Numpy, I just don't see it. Let's define an example array containing some missing values:

```
import numpy as np
input_data = np.array([[1,3,5,8,6],[3,np.nan,np.nan,5,6],[np.nan,6,7,np.nan,2]])

Out[530]: [[1, 3, 5, 8, 6], [3, nan, nan, 5, 6], [nan, 6, 7, nan, 2]]
```

What I'm looking for is to get an array that gives me for each element the distance to the previous valid value in each row. In the example above, this would be something like:

```
delta_valid = [[nan, 1, 1, 1, 1], [nan, 1, 2, 3, 1], [nan, nan, 1, 1, 2]]
```

The first element in each row would always be NaN because there is no previous value (not sure if there's a better way to define this).

Who can help me getting this result in Numpy? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically make ranges of `(1,2,3,...)` until the next `non-NaN`. To solve such cases, we could use some `diff` + `cumsum` magic on each row, as shown below -

```
def closest_distance_per_row(a):
    m0 = np.ones(a.shape,dtype=int)
    mask = ~np.isnan(a)
    for i,item in enumerate(a):
        idx = np.flatnonzero(mask[i])
        if len(idx)>0:
            m0[i,:idx[0]] = 0
            m0[i,idx[1:]] = idx[:-1] - idx[1:] +1

    out = np.full(a.shape,np.nan,dtype=float)
    out[:,1:] = m0[:,:-1].cumsum(1)
    out[out==0] = np.nan
    out[~mask.any(1)] = np.nan
    return out
```

Sample runs -

```
In [353]: a
Out[353]: 
array([[  1.,   3.,   5.,   8.,   6.],
       [  3.,  nan,  nan,   5.,   6.],
       [ nan,   6.,   7.,  nan,   2.]])

In [354]: closest_distance_per_row(a)
Out[354]: 
array([[ nan,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [ nan,   1.,   2.,   3.,   1.],
       [ nan,  nan,   1.,   1.,   2.]])

In [343]: a
Out[343]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   4.,  nan,   3.,   1.],
       [ nan,  nan,   6.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  0.,  nan,   2.,  nan,   1.,  nan,   0.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  3.,  nan,   2.,  nan,   8.,   6.,  nan,   4.,   2.,  nan],
       [ nan,   0.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,   2.,  nan,   0.,  nan,  nan,   1.,  nan,  nan]])

In [344]: closest_distance_per_row(a)
Out[344]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,   2.,   1.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
       [ nan,   1.,   2.,   1.,   2.,   1.,   2.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
       [ nan,   1.,   2.,   1.,   2.,   1.,   1.,   2.,   1.,   1.],
       [ nan,  nan,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,   2.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   1.,   2.]])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [4]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(5000,5000)).astype(float)

In [5]: a.ravel()[np.random.choice(a.size, int(a.size*0.5), replace=0)] = np.nan

In [6]: %timeit two_loops(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 16.7 s per loop

In [7]: %timeit closest_distance_per_row(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 339 ms per loop

In [8]: 16700/339.0 # Speedup with one loop (proposed in this post) over two loops
Out[8]: 49.26253687315634
```

Comment: Not that yours isn't quicker, but it would be possible to improve the run time of my solution quite a bit I guess, by pre-allocating an array in the `distance` function, rather than building a list and then convert it to an array.

Comment: @JohanL Would be happy to update my timings if you decide to update your code with it. Let me know if you do.

Comment: Great solution! I'll flag it as the best answer, as it includes both solutions. @JohanL, if yours would get updated, I guess this could be edited in this answer as well. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: @Kristof Just stating the discliamer as I have commented as well in my post that I have included JohanL's solution for timing purpose only and credit to that solution goes to the author of the original post itself.

Comment: @Divakar Not sure what you mean, do I have to change something?
By the way, your solution fails on all-NaN rows. Easy fix I guess, but worth mentioning.

Comment: @Kristof Edited to handle all NaNs cases. That disclaimer was directed at SO community in general and meant to just state that I don't claim any authority on JohanL's solution.

Comment: @Divakar I have updated my solution now, and with the update the run times are much more similar, even though, as I expected, your solution still outperforms mine.

Comment: @JohanL Updated, but the speedups stay the same. I guess its just that looping with NumPy isn't the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to your problem. It might not be optimal, as I it might be possible to do something more fancy with map and/or list comprehensions but at least it solves your immediate issue:

```
import numpy as np
input_data = np.array([[1,3,5,8,6],[3,np.nan,np.nan,5,6],[np.nan,6,7,np.nan,2]])

def distance(vector):
    dist = np.nan
    dists = []
    for a in vector:
        dists.append(dist)
        dist = dist + 1 if np.isnan(a) else 1
    return np.array(dists)

dists = np.empty(input_data.shape)
for row_num, row in enumerate(input_data):
    dists[row_num, :] = distance(row)
```

It also only works for 2d arrays currently, but it could probably be generalized pretty easily.

Also, the above piece of code is not very optimized. In order to make a more fair comparison with the accepted answer, here comes a more optimized version, with no extra function calls, or list builds:

```
def two_loops(input_data):
    dists = np.empty(input_data.shape)
    for row_num, row in enumerate(input_data):
        dist = np.nan
        for col_num, value in enumerate(row):
            dists[row_num, col_num] = dist
            dist = dist + 1 if np.isnan(value) else 1
    return dists
```

This makes the execution times are more similar. When I measure, my solution takes about twice as long to execute.

Comment: Great! This works indeed! I will try it on the real data, which is much larger in size, and hopefully, speed will not be too much of an issue. Let's see if someone else can further filter out the for loops in your answer to speed up things. Until then, happy to accept your answer, thank you!